# Reuse methods from locust in different tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, locust

I currently have this locust test:

```
import logging
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task, constant

log = logging.getLogger("rest-api-performance-test")


def get_headers():
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
    }
    return headers


def headers_token(auth_token):
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": str(auth_token),
    }
    return headers


class LoginTasks(TaskSet):
    def post_login(self):
        headers = get_headers()
        login_response = self.client.post("/api/auth",
                                          json={"key": "cstrong@tconsumer.com", "secret": "cstrong"},
                                          headers=headers, catch_response=False, name="Login")
        login_data = login_response.json()
        auth_token_value = login_data["results"][0]["auth-token"]
        return auth_token_value


class UserTasks(UserTasks):
    @task
    def test_get_list_of_workers(self):
        auth_token = self.post_login()
        try:
            with self.client.get("/api/client/workers",
                                 headers=headers_token(auth_token), catch_response=True,
                                 name="Get Worker Lists") as request_response:
                if request_response.status_code == 200:
                    assert (
                            '"label": "Salena Mead S"' in request_response.text
                    )
                    request_response.success()
                    log.info("API call resulted in success.")

                else:
                    request_response.failure(request_response.text)
                    log.error("API call resulted in failed.")

        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f"Exception occurred! details are {e}")


class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    host = "https://test.com"
    wait_time = constant(1)
    tasks = [UserTasks]
```

the tests runs as expected but `post_login` is required by multiple tests since is the one who generates the authentication token used by most of the APIs that I'm testing, is there a way to avoid use inheritance from class `LoginTasks` and find a better solution? The reason I want to avoid it is `post_login` is not the only method that is going be used many times so I don't want to use multiple inheritance on my `UserTasks` class.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the function out of the class and pass in the client you want it to use.

```
def post_login(client):
    headers = get_headers()
    login_response = client.post("/api/auth",
    …
```

You can then call it when you need it the same way you call `get_headers()`.

```
auth_token = post_login(self.client)
```